# How to get the PayPal refresh token through API call in iOS

Tags: ios, curl, paypal, parameter-passing, paypal-sandbox

I have successfully implemented profile sharing option with PayPal iOS Sdk.
I am getting proper code once user logged in to paypal account in the app.
I have tried to get the user information with **curl** command I got success.

Now I want to implement 2nd and 3rd step through api call.

Below is what I have implemented for getting refresh token from PayPal server.

```
 func getTheRefreshToken(authToken:NSString) {

        print("Token \(authToken)")
        let urlPath: String = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/tokenservice"
        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
        let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

        let basicAuthCredentials: String = "AXvaZH_Bs9**CLIENTID**0RbhP0G8Miw-y:ED_xgio**SECRET**YFwMOWLfcVGs"
        let plainData = (basicAuthCredentials as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let base64String = "Basic \(plainData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0)))"

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let params = ["grant_type":"authorization_code","redirect_uri":"urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob", "authorization_code":authToken as String] as Dictionary<String, String>
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue(base64String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.timeoutInterval = 60
        request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])
        request.HTTPShouldHandleCookies=false

        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) in

            let refreshResponse = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSISOLatin1StringEncoding)
            print("Response \(refreshResponse!)")
        }
    }
```

Every time I am getting the error with grant_type as null.

**Error**

```
Response {"error_description":"Grant type is null","error":"invalid_grant","correlation_id":"e5d4cc9c47d21","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#errors"}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things here... 
1. You should never have your client Secret stored on the client side for security reasons.
2. Can you attempt the call from your server using the curl commands outline [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/profile_sharing_server.md#obtain-oauth2-tokens) and let me know the result?

The only thing I can see from our internal logs is the same as the error or grant_type missing.  Running the test from your server, using the authorization code in the response, should let us know if it's just something in your code that's getting discombobulated.

Comment: I have already done the curl command and its give me a correct result. I just want to skip the server side integration. I have already solved the issue. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Using this code you can refresh or got new Access token on PayPal.

```
NSString *clientID = @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
NSString *secret = @"YOUR_SECRET";

NSString *authString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", clientID, secret];
NSData * authData = [authString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *credentials = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
[configuration setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{ @"Accept": @"application/json", @"Accept-Language": @"en_US", @"Content-Type": @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", @"Authorization": credentials }];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"]];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

NSString *dataString = @"grant_type=client_credentials";
NSData *theData = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSURLSessionUploadTask *task = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:theData completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"data = %@", [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error]);
    }
}];    
[task resume];
```

This will give this Response.

```
 data = {
 "access_token" = "A101.S6WF1CZIz9TcamYexl6k1mBsXhxEL1OWtotHq37UVHDrK7roty_4DweKXMhObfCP.7hNTzK62FqlDn3K9bqCjUIFmsVy";
    "app_id" = "APP-80W284485P519543T";
    "expires_in" = 32042;
    nonce = "2016-12-26T10:24:12Z8qEQBxdSGdAbNMg2ivVmUNTUJfyFuSL30OI_W9UCgGA";
    scope = "https://uri.paypal.com/services/subscriptions https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card https://uri.paypal.com/services/applications/webhooks openid https://uri.paypal.com/payments/payouts https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.*";
    "token_type" = Bearer;
    }
```